# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null when binding tags json data which might be null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, antd

I have in my database some records, and not all of them have tags, some might be empty, they are stored on CosmosDb and returned as a Json array.

I am using antd table and tags:
https://ant.design/components/table/

Example: Tags

I have the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  Table, Tag} from 'antd';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';
import Notification from '../../components/notification';

class ListPageTemplatesWithSelection extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
    }

    fetchData = () => {
        adalApiFetch(fetch, "/PageTemplates", {})
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => {
            if (!this.isCancelled) {
                const results= responseJson.map(row => ({
                    key: row.Id,
                    Name: row.Name,
                    SiteType: row.SiteType,
                    Tags: row.Tags
                  }))
              this.setState({ data: results });
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };


    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();
    }

    render(){
        const columns = [
                {
                    title: 'Id',
                    dataIndex: 'key',
                    key: 'key',
                }, 
                {
                    title: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'Name',
                    key: 'Name',
                }, 
                {
                    title: 'Site Type',
                    dataIndex: 'SiteType',
                    key: 'SiteTy[e',
                },{
                  title: 'Tags',
                  key: 'Tags',
                  dataIndex: 'Tags',
                  render: Tags => (
                    <span>
                      {Tags.map(tag => {
                        let color = tag.length > 5 ? 'geekblue' : 'green';
                        if (tag === 'loser') {
                          color = 'volcano';
                        }
                        return <Tag color={color} key={tag}>{tag.toUpperCase()}</Tag>;
                      })}
                    </span>
                  ),
                }
        ];

        const rowSelection = {
            selectedRowKeys: this.props.selectedRows,
            onChange: (selectedRowKeys) => {
              this.props.onRowSelect(selectedRowKeys);
            }
          };


        return (
            <Table rowSelection={rowSelection}  columns={columns} dataSource={this.state.data} />
        );
    }
}

export default ListPageTemplatesWithSelection;
```

However I have this error:

```
 58 | dataIndex: 'Tags',
  59 | render: Tags => (
  60 |   <span>
> 61 |     {Tags.map(tag => {
  62 |       let color = tag.length > 5 ? 'geekblue' : 'green';
  63 |       if (tag === 'loser') {
  64 |         color = 'volcano';
```

I am not sure if this error its because some rows dont have tags, or if the error its for a different reason, anyways, not sure what I should do to avoid this.

Comment: if you expect `Tags` to be null or undefined, you can just put a condition before `map`. Something similar to `Tags && Tags.map` or use `ternary operator to return a empty `jsx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Tags might be null then you must add a check so that you don't map over it to render

```js
<span>
  {Tags && Tags.map(tag => {
    let color = tag.length > 5 ? 'geekblue' : 'green';
    if (tag === 'loser') {
      color = 'volcano';
    }
    return <Tag color={color} key={tag}>{tag.toUpperCase()}</Tag>;
  })}
</span>
```

Comment: Another way will be `Tags: row.Tags || []`

Comment: @llSanchez yes there can be multiple ways to handle the same but the idea is to not map over a non-array

Answer (score 1):

you can try to check if Tag exists or not before mapping it

```
render: Tags => (
    <span>
      { Tags ? Tags.map(tag => {
        let color = tag.length > 5 ? 'geekblue' : 'green';
        if (tag === 'loser') {
          color = 'volcano';
        }
        return <Tag color={color} key={tag}>{tag.toUpperCase()}</Tag>;
      })
      : ''}
    </span>
)
```